# Storing list date in table and label value in case when based from that table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a datetime data in which I want to label them in another column based on there day. So basically to mark whether each timestamp are in what type (weekday, weekend, holiday)

For weekday and weekend, I used this:

```
select case 
       when extract ( dow from date_period ) in (0,6)
       then 'weekend'
       when extract ( dow from date_period ) in (1,2,3,4,5)
       then 'weekday'
 from table;
```

Holiday will be assigned to datetime for a specific day. In which I have a list of the day that are holiday.

My first question here is that, how should I store those list of holiday in table. What I thought is one column for name and another column for datetime. It should be simple like that but in my case, I have to check with holiday datetime for different timezone. (not UTC) Let say UTC+7, when turned to UTC the date will be like `(previous-day) 17:00:00+00`. So, in this case, should I store datetime data in 2 columns for start and end period? Or what is the way that most people use for this case?

My next question here is that how can I apply it to my `case when` to label those day as a holiday. My idea is to do something like this but not sure.

```
case when date_period in (select holiday_date from holiday_table)
     then 'holiday'
     when . . .
```

Edit:

I tried

```
create table hld (name varchar, hdate date);
insert into hld values ('xyz day', '2019-08-01');
```

and use

```
case when date_period in (select hdate from hld) then 'custom holiday' . . .
```

And the result that marked as a 'custom holiday' show only a date_period that is '2019-08-01 00:00:00' but there are more date_period in that day but never show as a custome holiday

Comment: I think most holiday tables use a `date` column, not a `datetime` column.  You would then compare the date in your timezone to the date in the table.  Note that there might be other columns such as `country`, because holidays differ by country.

Comment: So, basically store it in one date column and use `at time zone 'xxx'` when use with `case when` right?

Comment: Oh about the column like `country` is not necessary for my case. Those date are custom @GordonLinoff

Comment: But then if I use only a date. How can I specify that a date is in a timezone that I want it to be?

Comment: Why is the timezone interesting for the holiday? BTW: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY ;)

Comment: I have to check a holiday for a specific timezone. Let say 25/08/2019 which are a time from 25/08/2019 00:00 to 25/08/2019 23:59 at utc+7 but then if change to normal timezone utc+0, it will be 24/08/2019 17:00 to 25/08/2019 16:59 then.